# How can I set bazel option --output_user_root for Angular CLI

Tags: angular, bazel

My user root contains a space in it so I get the following error when trying to run `ng serve` with [bazel enabled](https://angular.io/guide/bazel):

> WARNING: Output user root "C:/Users/Simon Weaver/_bazel_Simon Weaver"
>   contains a space. This will probably break the build. You should set a
>   different --output_user_root.

I just cannot find **where** to put this option - everywhere I've tried - such as angular.json file under options, or directly on the command line - either complains or fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create (or modify) the `.bazelrc` file in your project root with the following content:

```
startup --output_user_root=<path/to/new/root>
```

This is equivalent to running `$ bazel --output_user_root=<path/to/new/root> build ...`

[See this page](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/2.0.0/guide.html#bazelrc) for more information on .bazelrc files.

Comment: Thanks - I did look for `.bazelrc` but didn't realize I could just create one myself.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm getting three errors in the output that I just can't seem to get past. `Querying for files to watch... )) was unexpected at this time.` and then all kinds of errors about not being able to compile sass like `BUILD.bazel:121:1 Compiling Sass failed (Exit 1)` and `'""' is not recognized as an internal or external command` and `Bazel query failed: exit status 255`. I think I'm giving up for today

Comment: Note to self - for other options separate with commas : `startup --output_user_root=bazelroot,--verbose_failures`

Comment: --verbose_failures is not a startup flag, but a flag for the `build` command. Add a new line `build --verbose_failures` instead.

Comment: In general, create a new `.bazelrc` row for every flag you want to associate with a bazel command, like this: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/.bazelrc

Comment: weird that syntax seemed to work -at least it gave me a 404 error about not being able to find a new version of node